# How do I stop the pointer disappearing when I type in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

I recently made a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my laptop that has a touchpad.

I assume it's a "feature" that my pointer keeps disappearing whenever I start typing. This occurs in any application, any place that takes text entry. However, I find it's not ideal for me. It seems to take a few moments for the pointer to come back to life after it's been hidden, which interrupts my sense of how the touchpad and pointer should be operating.

Where do I find the interface to control this behaviour and turn it off?

Comment: Start typing where? in the terminal, or in general? Could this be related? http://superuser.com/questions/902909/disabling-mouse-hiding-in-gnome-terminal-while-typing

Comment: @Thank you for responding. The mouse disappears whenever I type anywhere that typing can be done. Any application, any place that takes text entry. The link you provided seems to be talking about just Gnome Terminal, but what I am experiencing applies system wide to everything.

Comment: ok, can't help you more then - I run Xubuntu for a good reason :)

Comment: There is a small program that does exactly that - hide the mouse pointer when you start typing. It is called `unclutter`. You don't happen to have that running? (Also, you seem to mean the mouse pointer, not the cursor. The cursor is the vertical bar in a text field or window that indicates where the next letter will appear.)

Comment: @Jos It is called cursor in some languages though.

Comment: I think is this a GTK feature, because the pointer hides only when it is over the same input widget. I check Ubuntu Mate and I confirm same happening in Xubuntu too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATE, the settings has gone for some reason. But if you're referring to the disabling of cursor while typing, that settings can be disabled from gsettings.

Here is the command in gsettings command for MATE

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad disable-while-typing false
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have changed the pointer behaviour.

Comment: @Questioner If you set it to `true` or `false` does it change the behavior of the touchpad at all? If you cant move cursor while pressing keys (when it's set to `true`) then we can at least conclude that this direction doesnt contain the solution to the problem. :)

Comment: @Questioner That is the settings that control disable tapping while typing. Can you verify that you have synaptic device? What is the output of `xinput --list`?

Comment: Thank you for this response. Actually, for reasons unrelated to this question, I ended up re-installing MATE, and this time the pointer seems to be behaving more intuitively. Unfortunately, this means I can't verify this answer and follow up comments, but I appreciate you were pursuing the issue to help me, so I awarded the bounty here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Questioner You can at verify the behaviour now by altering `false` and `true`. Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise looking in **System Settings** (might be called slightly differently in your distro) section of **Mouse and Touchpad** or it might be called **Input devices**. At least in Kubuntu 16.04 and Xubuntu 14.04, that is where I found the checkbox **"Disable touchpad while typing"**. Unchecking that gave the desired results for me with the aforementioned 2 flavors of Ubuntu. I hope Mate is similar.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you find the settings? It was there a long ago, but not anymore.

Comment: I checked it definitely in Kubuntu 16.04 and Xubuntu 14.04

Comment: Well, Where is it in Kubuntu? Though You know the OP is it MATE

Comment: i wonder if this is a hardware or software cursor issue , i think there are some xorg settings for that

Comment: @Anwar Oh sorry, somehow missed the question. It is (on Kubuntu 16.04) under `System Settings > Input Devices > Touchpad > Enable/Disable Touchpad > Disable touchpad when typing`

Answer (score 1):

As @Carolus guessed, it is in the mouse properties. You can reach it from the Mate start menu by searching for "mouse", or by entering `mate-mouse-properties` in a terminal.

In the mouse properties window, choose the Touchpad tab and uncheck "disable touchpad while typing".